# print() throws TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, if-statement, tuples, typeerror, user-input

```
nama=input('Nama: ')
jenis=input('Jenis kelamin: ')
umur=input('Umur: ')
hari=input('Hari kerja: ')

if umur >='18' and umur <'30':
     if jenis=='wanita' :
          upah=750000
elif jenis=='pria' :
    upah=700000
if umur >='30' and umur <='40' :
     if jenis=='wanita' :
          upah=850000
elif jenis=='pria' :
    upah=800000
total = upah*hari

print(nama, 'menerima upah sebesar Rp.', total, 'karena telah bekerja', hari, 'hari')
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-2a7d3cefc5b8> in <module>
     16 total = upah*hari
     17 
---> 18 print(nama, 'menerima upah sebesar Rp.', total, 'karena telah bekerja', hari, 'hari')

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I want to get results like:

```
Nama: Anna
Jenis kelamin: wanita
Umur: 20
Hari kerja: 2

Anna menerima upah sebesar Rp. 1500000 karena telah bekerja 2 hari
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error [I do get *other* errors]. Are you sure you have not made a variable named `input` somewhere in your code?

Comment: The post title says TypeError, but in the post body you say it's a SyntaxError.  Which is it?  Please edit the question and post the full error message.

Comment: I'm sure because I just insert the input only at the beginning

Comment: Have you reassigned `print` somewhere in your code? As others have asked - please add the full error traceback to your question

Comment: Right.  Somewhere, you accidentally typed someting like `print=(a,b,c)`.  If you're using an IDE like Jupyter, it may be leftover from another frame.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `total` variable.

while you are doing `total = upah*hari` `upah` is in `int` and `hari` is in `str` so.

it just multiplying `2` to **750000 times**..

so total="2222 upto 750000times"  #total is in `str` format.

**To correct.**
you should change the type of `hari` you will get your desired output

**Code:**

```
nama=input('Nama: ')
jenis=input('Jenis kelamin: ')
umur=input('Umur: ')
hari=int(input('Hari kerja: '))  #change in here [type change to int]

if umur >='18' and umur <'30':
     if jenis=='wanita' :
          upah=750000
elif jenis=='pria' :
    upah=700000
if umur >='30' and umur <='40' :
     if jenis=='wanita' :
          upah=850000
elif jenis=='pria' :
    upah=800000
total = upah*hari
print(nama, 'menerima upah sebesar Rp.', total, 'karena telah bekerja', hari, 'hari')
```

**Output:**

```
Nama: Anna
Jenis kelamin: wanita
Umur: 20
Hari kerja: 2
Anna menerima upah sebesar Rp. 1500000 karena telah bekerja 2 hari
```

**Note*** In future if you have any operation which include `Umur` you should also convert it into `int` before operation.